# Is it possible to use custom iOS controls from a MonoTouch class library in Xcode (Interface Builder)?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, interface-builder, custom-controls

I am trying to move custom iOS controls from the main MonoTouch project to a MonoTouch class library in order to re-use them in other MonoTouch projects.

However, when I try to replace the class associated with the controls in Xcode, I can't find them. If I look at the structure of the temp Xcode project, it has a folder with my main project name, but no folder with my class library name. Thus no header file can be found for these controls.

If I move them back to the main project, it works again. If I try to the custom controls from the class library dynamically from code, it works fine. It's just a matter of making these classes available in Xcode.

So is there a way to use custom iOS controls from a MonoTouch class library in Xcode or do they have to be in the main project?

Thanks